# parse robot file in python

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a robot file , want to parse it in python and get the list of libraries used in it and also need to get keywords used and corresponsing arguments:

Here are contents of robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     OpenGoogle
Library           SeleniumLibrary    timeout=10
Test Teardown     Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
OpenGoogle Test
    Open Available Browser    https://www.google.com/
    Maximize Browser Window
    Input Text    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input    python tutorial
    Click Element    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/center/input[1]
    Sleep    3s
```

here is what i tried

```
from robot.api import TestSuiteBuilder



def parse_robot_file2(file_path):
    suite_builder = TestSuiteBuilder()
    suite = suite_builder.build(file_path)

    for testcase in suite.tests:
         
         print(f"{testcase}")
      
         for step in testcase.keywords:
             keyword = step.name
             arguments = step.args
             print(f"{keyword}({', '.join(arguments)})")

parse_robot_file2("robot_scriptt.robot")
```

It gives me below output:

```
Open Available Browser(https://www.google.com/)
Maximize Browser Window()
Input Text(/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input, python tutorial)
Click Element(/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/center/input[1])
Sleep(3s)
Close Browser()
```

Comment: Is there anything in https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.parsing.html to do this for you?

Comment: getting ImportError: cannot import name 'RobotParser' from 'robot.parsing.parser'. I have Robot Framework 6.0.2 (Python 3.7.9 on win32)

Comment: small note there: python 3.7 is [very close to](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) no longer being supported, and you really want to be on 3.11, which improves runtime *considerably* over older versions. Having said that, have you also asked the folks who maintain the Robot framework? (If not, remember to do so. After searching their docs and issue tracker etc. of course)